# using SMV 'ovo' with RandomUnderSampler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, imblearn

I am doing classification with imbalanced dataset. I understand sklearn's `SVM` does have a `decision_function_shape` hyperparameter which can be set to `'ovo'` for 'one against one' (although `SVM` does an `'ovo'` by default).

Since I choose to do an `'ovo'` with under-sampling, I am interested in down-sampling the majority class in the `'ovo'` participating classes, to the size of the minority class, before fitting each of the `'ovo'` models. To make myself clear, suppose I have dataset with the following 4 classes:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from collections import Counter

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,  n_classes=4, 
            weights=[.1, .15, .2], n_informative=3, random_state=11)

Counter(y)
Counter({0: 103, 1: 151, 2: 200, 3: 546})
```

In an `SVM 'ovo'` decision function, There  would be `nC2` i.e. `4C2 = 6` models. So in each `'ovo'` model, majority class undersampling should go like so:

```
Model 1 = Class 0 Vs Class 1 # maj:1=151; RUS to 103, -> 0:103, 1:103 
Model 2 = Class 0 Vs Class 2 # maj:2=200; RUS to 103  -> 0:103, 2:103
Model 3 = Class 0 Vs Class 3 # maj:3=546; RUS to 103, -> 0:103, 3:103
Model 4 = Class 1 Vs Class 2 # maj:2=200; RUS to 151  -> 1:151, 2:151
Model 5 = Class 1 Vs Class 3 # maj:3=546; RUS to 151  -> 1:151, 3:151
Model 6 = Class 2 Vs Class 3 # maj:3=546; RUS to 200  -> 2:200, 3:200
```

Precisely, number of examples (balanced) in each participating  classes depend on number of examples on which ever is the minority.

How do I integrate this with strategy with `sklearn`'s [SVC()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and `imblearn`'s [RUS()](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it would be readily done using the `SVC`'s multiclass handling, because that appears to be delegated to `libsvm`.

You could presumably use the `OneVsOneClassifier`, with its `estimator` being an `imblearn` pipeline containing the sampler and an `SVC` (which would now only see a binary problem).

Comment: I see, but then I'm doing one-against-one among participating classes, how does `OneVsRestClassifier` fits in here?

Comment: oops, typed the wrong one.  Fixed.